# Can we use VoIP push for normal push notification?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, voip, ios13

I am creating a VoIP related app. I have to also receive normal notifications. Can we use VoIP push for receiving normal push notification in iOS 13? If yes how can I handle this in "didReceiveIncomingPushWith" method?

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't want to do this.

In iOS 13, Apple began enforcing when your app receives a VoIP push notification, your app needs to notify the user of the incoming call using a combination of PushKit and CallKit. If you don't properly handle the incoming push, your app will stop notifying the user of incoming calls, breaking your VoIP feature.

Comment: That means I have to show call window UI whenever i receive VoIP pushes. right?

Comment: That's correct. This was implemented because some apps were silently using VoIP pushes to keep their apps alive in the background without there being an actual call.